# In Wix how do I format version from X.X.X.X to X.X.X

Tags: .net, installation, wix, versioning

I have a product where the customers expect a 3 part version number like 1.2.3 but internally we use 1.2.3.4. The version is set automatically in the Wix installer, so how do I drop the last number (4)?.

**Context**

The last number, in the example '4', is the subversion commit number that is automatically generated. Our customers do not want to see "release 5.6.1.7654" but want to see "release 5.6.1". That is the nature of our market. We do display the full number in the Help | About dialog.

**Implementation**

In the Wix XML we have:

```
  <?define ProductVersion="!(bind.FileVersion.MyExe)" ?>
      :
  <Product 
      :
       Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
      :
```

How do I format the $(var.ProductVersion) from X.X.X.X to X.X.X?

Thanks in advance

Rob

Answer (score 1):

There is a special assembly property meant for this, `AssemblyInformationalVersion`. It would be the best choice, since it also allows you to specify text, like "Release 5.6.1 RC1".
However, I'm not sure the [WIX toolset support it yet](http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/2918/).

Another thing you can do is to use a global `AssemblyInfo.cs` technique in your project/solution. Define the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` in that file as you want them to be presented to the user and keep using 4 stage incremental build numbers on your other assemblies.

Comment: HI Magnus, the assemblies have the version numbers in their AssemblyInfo.cs files already and have been compiled. My question here is how to format the version returned from that info in Wix. That is, when building the installer. Not the assemblies.

Comment: Ah ... with further investigation I see what your saying ... thank you.

Comment: The target app is .Net 2.0, and it looks like WIX does not support this attribute. So, informative but not useful.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do all that with the preprocessor instead of the binder. That's how I do it anyway. I wrote a preprocessor extension that takes a version number (string) as parameter and returns a new one. So you could do the same, such as:

```
switch (function)
{
    case "TruncateVersion":
        // validate version number here
        return args[0].Substring(0, args[0].LastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Here's a link on how to extend the preprocessor: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development_preprocessor.htm

Then, you could get your version number using `$(version.TruncateVersion($(var.MyProject.TargetPath)))`.

Of course, that's only the path. You can extract the file version using the `FileVersionInfo` class or grab it directly from your AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Or, if you'd rather do the work at bind time, you could write a binder extension. Unfortunately, WiX extensions are poorly documented at the moment and only the preprocessor seems to have a complete, documented example. Although I've seen fragments of Heat extensions here and there.

Feel free to prove me wrong by checking the WiX source code or scouring the net. Good luck!

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention. You cannot use this syntax: 
`$(version.TruncateVersion(!(bind.fileVersion.FileID)))`

This is because the preprocessor variables, starting with *'$'*, are resolved *before* bind variables are resolved by the binder, which start with *'!'*.

You can, however, do the opposite: !(bind.fileVersion.$(var.MyProject.TargetPath))

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach will be to have assemblyversionInfo in project and use the version number from this file

[image]